# Update Button UI in a TableViewCell with Firebase Firestore

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the same issue with both 'Follow' buttons and 'Like' buttons in my app.

I've seen in the Firebase Firestore documentation how to add the data when pressed and how to delete records, however, I'm having trouble updating the initial states of the buttons to be selected or not when the view loads.

Would this be done in the awakeWithNib? And would you add a snapshot listener?

FollowerCell.swift

```
class FollowerCell: UITableViewCell {

// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var friendImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var followButton: SpringButton!

// MARK: - Variables
var userId:String!
var db:Firestore!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    friendImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    db = Firestore.firestore()

    self.setFollowingButton()
}

// MARK: - Functions
func setFollowingButton() {
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let followerDB = db.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).collection("followers").whereField("follower", isEqualTo: true)
        followerDB.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                    self.followButton.isSelected = true
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func followButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if followButton.isSelected == true {
        followButton.isSelected = false
        // add follower
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid).collection("following").document("\(userId!)").setData([
                "name":self.nameLabel.text ?? "",
                "following":true
            ])  { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("\(self.userId!) added to followers")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        followButton.isSelected = true
        // delete following
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid).collection("following").document("\(userId!)").delete() { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("\(self.userId!) successfully removed!")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your Firestore collection (or query) populates a table (where every Firestore document corresponds to one table row.)  I would have your FollowerCell take the Firestore document as a property (or via method). Then have the FollowerCell update its own buttons based on the document.

Comment: still have issues calling it tho.  if i call the function in awakeWithNib it returns nil unless a set a timer to call it after a second

Comment: Don't call it from *awakeFromNib*.  Call it from the tableViewDelegate's *cellForRowAt* method - this when you should be configuring the cell, after the dequeue and before returning it.

Comment: Ahh thanks @AgRizzo.  Kept trying to call a function from the cell but it worked when I just made the function inside the tableview and used a property from the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class FollowersTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Variables
var db:Firestore!
let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
var followerArray = [User]()
var followingArray = [String]()

// MARK: - ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    db = Firestore.firestore()

    SVProgressHUD.show()
    getFollowers()
    getFollowing()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return followerArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "followerCell", for: indexPath) as! FollowerCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let user = followerArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = user.name
    cell.userId = user.documentId
    // Set follow button state
    if followingArray.contains(cell.userId) {
        cell.followButton.isSelected = false
    } else {
        cell.followButton.isSelected = true
    }

    let userImageRef = storage.child("\(user.documentId)"+"/profile_pic.jpg")
    // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
    userImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred! Display Default image
            print("Error - unable to download image: \(error)")
            cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(named: "userProfileGray")
        } else {
            // Data for "locationImages/(locationId).jpg" is returned
            cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 71
}

// MARK: - Functions
func getFollowers() {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let followingDB = db.collection("users").document("\(user.uid)").collection("followers").whereField("follower", isEqualTo: true)
        followingDB.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                    self.followerArray.append(User(name: document["name"] as! String, documentId: document.documentID))
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func getFollowing() {
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let followingDB = db.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).collection("following").whereField("following", isEqualTo: true)
        followingDB.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                    self.followingArray.append(document.documentID)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}